# Magnific Popup - Error when opening a you tube video

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

Can not get a video to play in the magnific pop up window.
When I use `class=iframe`, the page will redirect to youtube and play the video.
But when I use `class=popup-youtube`, the popup will display, but I receive the following error message:

This webpage is not found

> No webpage was found for the web address: `file://www.youtube.com/embed/AcnImfXjBHo?autoplay=1`
> Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a class="popup-YouTube" href="HTTP://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcnImfXjBHo">
                                Trial Master File Video</a>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,

            fixedContentPos: false
        });
    });
```

I am running this locally on my PC through IIS for testing. My other links that I set up for single images, gallery images and a google map work fine with magnific pop up. The video is the only one not working.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that you're running this code in server environment, or add `https:` to youtube src option http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe-type

Comment: Dmtiry - Thank you!. That was the problem. It now works like a champ. Perhaps you should add that to the documentation, for people like myself who are testing on a local machine before deploying.

Comment: I was having the same problem, but now works perfectly. I also think that it would be great if the documentation have this detail.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I ran it in server environment.

Comment: @Dmitry Semenov  I am facing with the same problem images works fine but videos don't get loaded. I am not running on the server it is locally and I include video src with https:// - no result at all. Here is what I have 
 <a  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nw1ORBXpA_c" class="popup-youtube">Video YouTube </a>

Answer (score 5):

Add the code inside the **extend** function for every popup like this:

```js
$.extend(true, $.magnificPopup.defaults, {
    iframe: {
        patterns: {
           youtube: {
              index: 'youtube.com/', 
              id: 'v=', 
              src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' 
          }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Warning: explicitly setting http: protocol will prevent the original intention of automatically the current protocol. But because it's linking to an external site then it's not really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Something I found with "v" argument, I see patterns in core file "jquery.magnific-popup.js"

```
patterns: {
    youtube: {
        index: 'youtube.com',
            id: 'v=',
            src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1'
        }
}
```

Frontend link:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YQHsXMglC9A" class="popup-youtube">youtube link</a>
```

I gave link to A tag "https" url but not work.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A" class="popup-youtube">youtube link</a>
```

I see valid url "v" argument with video code "YQHsXMglC9A" and it's works :) 
so we just need to change "v" argument value.

Answer (score 0):

Arrg! This took me a while to figure out. The class "popup-YouTube" should be all lowercase.

Instead of

```
<a class="popup-YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcnImfXjBHo">
                                Trial Master File Video</a>
```

Note the capital letters in `YouTube`

It should be

```
<a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcnImfXjBHo">
                                Trial Master File Video</a>
```

Comment: The case sensitivity of your class doesn't matter as long as you're using the identical case in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`<a class="popup-YouTube" href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcnImfXjBHo">
                                Trial Master File Video</a>`

remove "HTTP:" OR "HTTPS:". the issue is with if your site is opening with HTTP and your popup video URL is starting with HTTPS then it will redirect you to the page.