# Which is actually the best (and fastest) way to add a popup video using HTML + CSS + Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, load

I'm working on a website and trying to add a popup video attached to an  tag.

I've seen two or three possible solutions to my problem, but they didn't work the way I'd like them to. Some of the guides were made 10 years ago and are outdated too.

The last thing I tried was the "Magnific popup" method, I could insert the popup, but the video didn't load:

[image: Image of what is happening]

**HTML**

```
 <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwGf3ZH1ZUQ">Open YouTube video</a><br>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,

        fixedContentPos: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917624/magnific-popup-error-when-opening-a-you-tube-video

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download the video and, instead of importing the video from youtube, import it from you local storage.

`<video src="video.mp4" width="420" height="240"></video>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunatelly won't work, because I need the website depends on the user inserting youtube videos.